# When clicking on a button on IOS, iframe is not scrolling

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, scroll

I am trying to scroll down to some element when clicking on a button. But it isn't working.

The way I am using to do that is using query:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|Android)/)) {
    console.log('ios');

    $("html, body, .wrapper").animate({
        scrollTop: offset
    }, 500);
} else {

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: offset
    }, 500);
}
```

Those cases are almost the same, just read somewhere that animate is not working on html and body tags on ios.

However still can't make it work.

This is inside:

```
$(".elem").click(function () {
    var offset = somenumber;
    //and the code above
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I've fixed it, is that I used jquery plugin called postMessage, which is a good way for cross-domain frame communication.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/